# execute command on all files and store in new directory using the file name in script argument

Tags: bash

I want to run a script on all files in my directories with a .fa extension. The script has an argument for the output directory and I want to use the file name for this argument.

To run the script on one file, I would use:

```
metaerg.pl  --dbdir /projects/p30777/db DeMMO1_10.fa --sp --tm --outdir DeMMO1_10  --force
```

where DeMMO1_10.fa is the file name and DeMMO1_10 is the name of the new directory being created for the output. There are ~500 of these files split into six directories. I want to run something like:

```
find . -name '*.fa' -exec metaerg.pl  --dbdir /projects/p30777/db {} --sp --tm --outdir {}  --force \;
```

but I'm not sure what to put for the --outdir argument so that it passes in just the file name without the .fa extension or the rest of the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.fa' -exec sh -c 'metaerg.pl  --dbdir /projects/p30777/db {} --sp --tm --outdir `basename $1 .fa`  --force' sh {} \;
```

We create a subshell and pass a `{}` placeholder from find-exec to it as a `$1` parameter (last `sh` being `$0` just for the sake of consistency). Within subshell, we take `$1` parameter and use it within backticks to evaluate the `basename()` and emplace the resulting text as an argument to `outdir`.

Comment: thanks @vtronko , I just tested find . -name '*.fa' -exec basename {} .fa \; which returned just the file names without the extensions. Can you explain why I need quotes around `basename {} .fa` for the script argument?

Comment: Those are backticks. You can read above them here — https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48392/understanding-backtick

Comment: thanks @vtronko, looks like it didn't work quite right, just tried to run it as a batch job and it failed with the error: [Thu Apr  2 11:50:17 2020] Creating new output folder: ./DeMMO1_4.fa
[Thu Apr  2 11:50:17 2020] Running: mkdir -p \.\/DeMMO1_4\.fa
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘./DeMMO1_4.fa’: File exists
[Thu Apr  2 11:50:17 2020] Could not run command:mkdir -p \.\/DeMMO1_4\.fa

Comment: Are you sure that has nothing to do with your Perl script on its own? For example, it may not handle the situation when a directory already exists. Maybe the existence of duplicates is the problem? I am not sure what logic you employ in your script, but maybe find walks in output directories produced by earlier inputs and treats them as a new input. 

Seems like unrelated issue to me from what I can observe.

Comment: the purpose of the --force flag is to overwrite pre-existing directories so there shouldn't be an issue with that. The error looks like `basename {} .fa` is assigning the file name with the extension as the directory name.

Comment: @Caitlin I overlooked how it actually expanded. I hope an edited solution will work for you.